# Path to a file in the Extensions Folder

Tags: swift

I am trying to find a path to file in the extensions folder, but unfortunately, the app crashes every time while doing this. I really have no clue as to why its happening. Any suggestions?

[image: Screenshot Image]

The file is located in the Keyboard Folder and its called StickersList.plist

The code is being generated in the viewDidLoad() inside KeyboardViewController.swift

```
if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "StickersList", ofType: ".plist") {
    print("I got in")
    print(path)
    let dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path) as! Dictionary<String,AnyObject>
    let allSections = dict["Sections"] as? [[String:AnyObject]]
    print(allSections)
    if let selectedSections = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "selectedSections") as? [Int] {
        for index in selectedSections {
            self.data.append((allSections![index]))
        }
    }
}
```

it crashes as soon as it runs the if statement. Any suggestions?

Comment: This does not explain a crash, but if I remember correctly, you must not include the dot in the suffix parameter: `Bundle.main.path(forResource: "StickersList", ofType: "plist")`

Comment: tried removing the dot, still the same